# Return response and not source code in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have code which use `fetch` in `javascript` to get html source of remote url. The code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="output"></p>
<script>
function getRandomDifferent(arr, last = undefined) {
  if (arr.length === 0) {
    return;
  } else if (arr.length === 1) {
    return arr[0];
  } else {
    let num = 0;
    do {
      num = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
    } while (arr[num] === last);
    return arr[num];
  }
}
  

const arr = ['https://gdrivex.github.io','https://gdrivex.github.io','https://gdrivex.github.io','https://gdrivex.github.io'];
const r1 = getRandomDifferent(arr);

fetch (r1)
.then(x => x.text())
.then(y => document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = y);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now above code perfectly return source of external url. Now when I use `file_get_contents` in php to get content which was retrieved using above code hosted on `.html` page return me above code itself, whereas I want to get code which was retrieved and not the code which is trying to retrieve. Also I can't directly use `file_get_contents` for the source code I want to retrieve. Is their anything I can do in php to retrieve the code?

Comment: your javascript executes in your browser while php executes on your server. You can send the fetched data or the particular URL from which you got your data from to your server via ajax, and then process it.

Comment: @Ivan86 Is their anything I can do in javascript code itself that it does `echo` thing and has that code in html source itself. (now it uses document.get... thing) so then I can use `file_get_contents` and then regex it...?

Comment: I believe not, since the data is being fetched dynamically and is not part of the static HTML.

Comment: May I ask what is the use-case? I can't think of a reason to do it the way you are describing anyways.

Comment: Are you using some kind of cron job on the server side?

Comment: @Ivan86 The url I have mentioned above is just for example. Now the url which i am trying to fetch cannot be fetched in php using `file_get_contents` or `curl` or `proxy` the site prevents it. But it does gets loaded using javascript. And that's reason I cannot use php directly in first place.

Comment: I'll give you a quick example of an alternative approach. It's not possible to do it the way you are describing. You must send it to the server if using javascript is the only way you can fetch it.

Comment: @Ivan86 Please if you could share example, that would be helpful.

Comment: @Ivan86 In my code variable y is showing not defined in console. What datastring should I pass in XMLHttpRequest then? I tried `var data = y;` but still it shows undefined reference . `Uncaught ReferenceError: y is not defined`

Comment: what about when running console.log on x?

Comment: @Ivan86 It shows same for that too. `var data = x;` `Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined`

Comment: This should work for you: `fetch (r1)
.then(x => x.text())
.then(y => sendData(y));`

Comment: Did it solve your problem?

Comment: @Ivan86 Thanks. now it is sending the post. But now I have integrated your code and my code in same php page and now the php code is `<?php $input = $_POST; print_r($input);?>` But it showing an empty array. Both the javascript and post php code in same page.

Comment: @Ivan86 My complete code. can you check: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gdrivex/iframe/gh-pages/post.php `print_r` is not returning anything

Comment: Try adding `xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");` before the `xhttp.send()` and in the send do this `xhttp.send("data="+someDataString);`, then in PHP do this `$data = $_POST['data']`

Comment: also, try `echo $data` instead of `print_r($data);`

Comment: @Ivan86 Now it does nothing. Not even send post request.  I have updated code again. Please check https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gdrivex/iframe/gh-pages/post.php

Comment: @Ivan86 console says `ReferenceError: xhr is not defined` not defined. I did it the `xhttp.setReq` Now it says `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'setRequestHeader' on 'XMLHttpRequest': The object's state must be OPENED.`

Comment: I see the problem.... your PHP code is inside the same file. It should be in a separate file and change the URL in the sendData function to point to that file. For example: make a new file called someFile.php and then add the PHP code there. If you want to check if it received the proper code, add the `xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() { ...` part from my answer to inside the sendData function under the `xhttp.open("POST", "https://example.com/pathToPhpFile/fileName.php", true);`. Then echo `$data` from the PHP file.

Comment: It's not a valid URL that's why it's not opened

Comment: @Ivan86 Okay, That worked. But then how would I get data then? Do I have log that everytime it is requested?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you are intending to do with the data. If you want to store it then you could store it in a database when received in the PHP file. I'm not sure I understand your last question.

Comment: @Ivan86 no problem. you helped me a lot. Tysm. Can you help me with last one. When using `xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");` I am getting following in console. `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'setRequestHeader' on 'XMLHttpRequest': The object's state must be OPENED` How to solve it?

Comment: You're welcome. It should work if you add `xhttp.setRequestHeader(...)` after `xhttp.open(...)` and before `xhttp.send(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a javascript function to send the data to the server using a `XMLHttpRequest object`:

```
function sendData(someDataString) {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("POST", "https://example.com/pathToPhpFile/fileName.php", true);
    xhttp.send(someDataString);
}
```

You can read more here: [MDN XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest).

You can also check for a confirmation from the server that it received the data by adding this to your function:

```
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        alert(this.responseText);
    }
};
```

You would send the confirmation from the PHP file by echoing.

Comment: How can I send received data using above code? What variables should I pass in above code to pass the data which received using my code?

Comment: @Andy you call the function `sendData` and pass in the fetched data as the variable `someDataString`. Set your URL instead of `https://example.com/...` and that's it.

Comment: @Andy you can rename the function and variable name, that's just for example